# Error writing a XML file in java

Tags: java, xml

I am trying to write an xml file using Java and I want to send a variable string to the method document.createElement(var) ,but it gives me that error:

```
"Exception in thread "main" org.w3c.dom.DOMException: INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: An invalid or illegal XML character is specified. 
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.CoreDocumentImpl.createElement(Unknown Source)
    at eg.edu.alexu.csd.oop.draw.WriteXML.<init>(WriteXML.java:47)
    at eg.edu.alexu.csd.oop.draw.Test.main(Test.java:25)"
```

this error because var is a variable

```
public class WriteXML {

public WriteXML() throws FileNotFoundException, ParserConfigurationException, IOException{
    DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document xmlDoc = docBuilder.newDocument();
    for(int i=0 ; i<shapes.length ; i++){
        //class
        s = shapes[i].getClass().getName().toString();
        Element rootElement =  xmlDoc.createElement(s);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A number cannot be used as a tag name. Here is a simplified test:

```
// Generates the error
DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document xmlDoc = docBuilder.newDocument();
xmlDoc.createElement("0");
```

You can use an attribute, or text content, to set the number.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document xmlDoc = docBuilder.newDocument();
xmlDoc.createElement("Red").setTextContent("0");
```

[XML Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-common-syn)

I am not sure, but I think the related line is:

> [Definition: A Name is an Nmtoken with a restricted set of initial characters.] Disallowed initial characters for Names include digits, diacritics, the full stop and the hyphen.

Comment: but s which i but in createElement(s) is a string

Comment: The type is a String, just like my example, but the character is a digit.